# Sound dropping when i plug earphones (Lumia 650)

Tags: sound, headset, lumia-650

The volume of all kinds of media players drops to 0 as soon as i plug in earphones. If I "draw" the volume up again, it drops immediately again. 
If I hold the finger on the display it will try to drop, but go up again.
Sometimes it will "calm down" for a minute or two - but then drop again.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Do these earphones have microphones built in to them at all?

Comment: Two pairs that I tried did, and one didn't. One had volume control - and two didn't.

Comment: did u get the same issue with other earphones recently?

Comment: I get the same issue with every kind of earphones that I've tried.